# How can I define a constraint on an inherited column in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a class inheritance scheme as layed out in http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance and I'd like to define a constraint that uses columns from both the parent and child classes.

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, CheckConstraint
)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String)
    name = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': type}


class Child(Parent):
    __tablename__ = 'child'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'), primary_key=True)
    child_name = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'child'}
    __table_args__ = (CheckConstraint('name != child_name'),)


engine = create_engine(...)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

This doesn't work because `name` isn't a column in `child`; I get the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "name" does not exist
 [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE child (\n\tid INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id), \n\tCHECK (name="something"), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES parent (id)\n)\n\n']
```

So how can I define such a constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tinkering I came up with a solution: create a "copy" `parent_name` column in `Child` that references `name` in `Parent`. It wastes some storage space, but that's probably unavoidable in order to have a real `CHECK CONSTRAINT`.

Here is the code:

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine, Column, Integer, String,
    CheckConstraint, UniqueConstraint, ForeignKeyConstraint
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError


Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': type}
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('id', 'name'),)


class Child(Parent):
    __tablename__ = 'child'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    child_name = Column(String, nullable=False)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'child'}
    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['id', 'parent_name'], ['parent.id', 'parent.name'],
            onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='CASCADE'
        ),
        CheckConstraint('parent_name != child_name'),
    )


engine = create_engine(...)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=True)()

print('Works without error:')
print('--------------------')

with session.begin():
    session.add(Child(name='a', child_name='b'))

print(session.query(Child).one().__dict__)

with session.begin():
    child = session.query(Child).one()
    child.name = 'c'

print(session.query(Child).one().__dict__)

print('\nFails due to IntegerityError:')
print('-------------------------------')
try:
    with session.begin():
        session.add(Child(name='a', child_name='a'))
except IntegrityError as e:
    print(e.orig)
    print(e.statement)
```

The output of this script is

```
Works without error:
--------------------
{'type': 'child', '_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f5e9b9b7898>, 'id': 1, 'child_name': 'b', 'parent_name': 'a', 'name': 'a'}
{'type': 'child', '_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f8fc80f2b38>, 'id': 1, 'child_name': 'b', 'parent_name': 'c', 'name': 'c'}

Fails due to IntegerityError:
-------------------------------
new row for relation "child" violates check constraint "child_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, a, a).

INSERT INTO child (id, parent_name, child_name) VALUES (%(id)s, %(parent_name)s, %(child_name)s)
```

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of the `UniqueConstraint` on the `Parent`, because it will never be violated anyways. And you solution is basically a duplication of information. I am not sure if this is a positive development or a negative one.

Comment: Without the `UniqueConstraint`, the `ForeignKeyConstraint` wouldn't work. I agree that preferably there would be no duplication, but I don't see any other way to have a real `CheckConstraint`.

Comment: Well, the problem is that even though you *think* you are checking that the `parent_name != child_name`, you are not checking that `parent_name != parent.name`. So back to square 1, don't you think?

Comment: The `ForeignKeyConstraint` ensures that `parent_name == parent.name`.

Comment: You are right. I did not realise that SA will take care about setting `parent_name` value because of the `FK`. Looks like your solution is pretty good, thanks for sharing.

Comment: I didn't know SQLAlchemy would do that either before trying it out. I wonder if it's in the documentation somewhere...?

Comment: One drawback that I can see with this approach is that you might not be able to change value for `name` (same as `parent_name`) because the ForeignKeyConstraint will kick in.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. However, setting `onupdate` should take care of it. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: **you cannot** do this using CHECK Constraint.

You cannot do it in the plain RDBMS, therefore you cannot do in using SQLAlchemy.
However, if all the data modifications are passing through your application (and not with direct DB access), you can add validation routines to your classes:

```
class Child(Parent):
    # ...

    @validates('child_name')
    def validate_child_name(self, key, child_name):
        assert child_name != name
        return child_name
```

Read more [Simple Validators](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/mapped_attributes.html#simple-validators).

Comment: I came up with a solution/workaround that I posted to this question. Do you think there are any unfortunate side effects with that solution (performance, etc.)?